# Implementing 1st Normal Form (1NF) using Core Data

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I have three main tables in my Core Data db.  All three of them have some attributes in common e.g. name.

Should I create a 4th table with these attributes in it and then create separate 1 to 1 relationships between this 'base' table and the other 3 tables or should I create duplicate attributes in all 3 tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the names are not related at all (e.g. 'publisher name', 'author name' and 'book name') then, no, leave them as attributes on each entity. You will pay a performance penalty if you move them to a 'Name' entity with no perceivable benefit.

If they are related (e.g. 'Manager' entity has 'name' and 'Employee' entity has 'name', and a manager can be an employee) then you might want to create a new entity (e.g. person).

Always keep performance in mind: it is OK to have a less-than-fully normalized model. Don't let theoretical perfection kill your performance. Remember this is an iPhone app not a datacenter.